# What is this turing machine doing

Tags: turing-machines

There is a following Turing machine. I want to understand what it is doing : 
[image]

I tried running it on input 100, 10000. Both these strings are accepted whereas 10,1000 are rejected 
That leads to a good guess that it's accepting the string's with 1 followed by 0's where number of 
0's = power of 2. But I can't prove it or deduce it from looking at the state diagram of it. 
Any insights into it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your interpretation is correct. $q_i$ and $q_{ii}$ are states that guarantee that $10$ and $100$ will be correctly accepted. It is clear that any other input of size $\leq 3$ will be rejected.

Now suppose you are in state $q_s$, the tape is $1Z^{2^k}u$ (with $u\in \{0,1\}^*$), and the head is in position of the first $Z$ of the tape. The cycle $q_s, q_d, q_r, q_l$ will let you do round trips, each trip transforming a $Z$ in $Y$, and a $0$ in $X$.

On the last trip, you will transform the last $Z$ in $Y$, then cross all $X$'s (in $q_{pf}$), and transform a zero in $X$. Therefore, if $u\neq 0^{2^k}v$, the Turing machine will reject. If not, we will get in $q_f$.

If $u = 0^{2^k}v$, then three cases are presented:

- $v = \varepsilon$, we finish in $q_{acc}$ so the word is accepted (and the input was necessarily $10^{2^{k+1}}$);
- $v = 1w$, we reject;
- $v = 0w$, we transform all $X$'s and $Y$'s into $Z$'s, reach the left most symbol (which must be 1), and finish in $q_s$. The tape is then $1Z^{2^{k+1}}v$ and we are in the first situation.